# Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap errorlevel=1

Tags: jmeter

On launching Jmeter, getting below error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap errorlevel=1.

Please help me to resolve this. I am using laptop with 4GB RAM, 64-bit OS, intel i-5 core.

Comment: check how much heap size you are allocating, try with low value i.e. xmx ans xms parameters.

Answer (score 4):

There could be a lot of processes running in your laptop. That is why you get this error. 
Stop all the unwanted programs.

Check the HEAP size setting in JMeter.bat file. Reduce it (128, 512, 1024..)

You need to do the following.

```
 Go to JMETER_HOME/bin folder
 Open "jmeter.bat"    (assuming you are using windows)
 Check "set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"      (check the heap size- change accordingly)
 Update, Close and Relaunch JMeter
```

You might need more heap for simulating more load.